# Компараторы С++

Tags: c++

Есть функция максимума из списка элементов типа T, один из параметров которой - компаратор comp.
Теперь я хочу забесплатно получить функцию минимума, поменяв компаратор на обратный. 
Сделать обратную функцию, передав третьим параметром comp, не получится, потому что функция максимума вызывает в себе функцию, один из параметров которой - bool(*comp)(T&,T&).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Ваш вопрос неясен. Поясните примером. В любом случае, если ваш код как-то требует именно компаратора типа `bool(*comp)(T&,T&)`, т.е. указатель на *обычную* функцию, то "обратить" ее и при этом снова получить в результате указатель на обычную функцию не получится. По крайней мере, это не удастся сделать реентерабельно без использования статических переменных. Чтобы свободно выполнять такие манипуляции на лету придется перейти на функциональные объекты, вместо обычных функций.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас есть функция сравнения вида

```
template <class T>
bool less( const T &, const T & );
```

то вы можете написать обертку для этой функции, которая будет выполнять роль оператора >.  (Здесь использована шаблонная функция лишь в целях демонстрации. Вместо нее можно использовать любую нешаблонную функцию.)

Например

```
template <class T>
bool greater( const T &x, const T &y ) { return less( y, x ); }
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class T>
bool less( const T &, const T & );

template <class T>
bool greater( const T &, const T & );

template <class T>
bool less( const T &x, const T &y ) { return x < y; }

template <class T>
bool greater( const T &x, const T &y ) { return less( y, x ); }


int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    int z = 10;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << less( x, y ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << greater( y, x ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << less( y, z ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << greater( y, z ) << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий:

```
true
true
false
false
```

Вот еще один пример, демонстрирующий, как можно использовать данный подход.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
bool less( const T &, const T & );

template <class T>
bool greater( const T &, const T & );

template <class T>
bool less( const T &x, const T &y ) { return x < y; }

template <class T>
bool greater( const T &x, const T &y ) { return less( y, x ); }


int main()
{
    const size_t  N = 7;
    int a[N] = { 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2 };

    std::cout << "The maximum value of array a[] is " 
              << *std::max_element( a, a + N, less<int> )
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The minimum value of array a[] is " 
              << *std::max_element( a, a + N, greater<int> )
              << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
The maximum value of array a[] is 8
The minimum value of array a[] is 1
```

Если имя функции сравнения заранее неизвестно, то можно использовать следующий подход, используя функцию преобразования. (Я написал собственную функцию max_element.)

```
#include <iostream>

const int * max_element( const int *first, const int *last, bool cmp( const int &, const int & ) )
{
    const int *max = first;

    if ( first != last )
    {
        while ( ++first != last )
        {
            if ( cmp( *max, *first ) ) max = first;
        }
    }

    return max;
}    

template <class T>
bool less( const T &x, const T &y ) { return x < y; }

template <class T>
struct Greater
{
    Greater( bool less( const T &, const T & ) )
    {        
        Greater::less = less;
    }       
    using greater = bool ( * )( const T &, const T & );
    static bool ( *less )( const T &, const T & );
    static bool f( const T &x, const T &y ) { return less( y, x ); } 
    operator greater() const { return f; } 
};    

template <class T>
bool ( *Greater<T>::less )( const T &, const T & );

int main()
{
    const size_t  N = 7;
    int a[N] = { 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2 };

    std::cout << "The maximum value of array a[] is " 
              << *max_element( a, a + N, less<int> )
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The minimum value of array a[] is " 
              << *max_element( a, a + N, Greater<int>( less<int> ) )
              << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы будет точно таким же, как и в предыдущем примере

```
The maximum value of array a[] is 8
The minimum value of array a[] is 1
```

Или, чтобы идея была более наглядной, можно переписать данную демонстрационную программу следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
bool less( const T &x, const T &y ) { return x < y; }

template <class T>
struct Greater
{
    Greater( bool less( const T &, const T & ) )
    {        
        Greater::less = less;
    }       
    using greater = bool ( * )( const T &, const T & );
    static bool ( *less )( const T &, const T & );
    static bool f( const T &x, const T &y ) { return less( y, x ); } 
    operator greater() const { return f; } 
};    

template <class T>
bool ( *Greater<T>::less )( const T &, const T & );

const int * max_element( const int *first, const int *last, bool cmp( const int &, const int & ) )
{
    const int *max = first;

    if ( first != last )
    {
        while ( ++first != last )
        {
            if ( cmp( *max, *first ) ) max = first;
        }
    }

    return max;
}    

const int * min_element( const int *first, const int *last, bool cmp( const int &, const int & ) )
{
    return max_element( first, last, Greater<int>( cmp ) );
}    

int main()
{
    const size_t  N = 7;
    int a[N] = { 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 4, 2 };

    std::cout << "The maximum value of array a[] is " 
              << *max_element( a, a + N, less<int> )
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The minimum value of array a[] is " 
              << *min_element( a, a + N, less<int> )
              << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы будет таким же, как показан ранее

```
The maximum value of array a[] is 8
The minimum value of array a[] is 1
```

Comment: Это легко, когда функция-компаратор _известна_. А как обратить неизвестный компаратор без лямбд?

Comment: @VladD  А что означает "неизвестный компаратор"? Достаточно того, что функция объявлена.

Comment: Ну, если у вас есть функция `find_max(container<T> container, bool(*comparator)(T&,T&))` без исходника, как определить функцию `find_min(container<T> container, bool(*comparator)(T&,T&))` (используя `find_max`)? То есть, чтобы обращение компаратора возложить не на вызывающую сторону, а на вызываемую.

Comment: @VladD Если вы имеете функцию find_max и функцию less, то find_min будет определяться как { return find_max( container, greater ); } где функция greater определена так, как я показал в своем ответе.

Comment: @VladD  Я привел дополнительный пример в своем ответе.

Comment: Я имел в виду случай, когда функция `less` нам заранее **не** известна. Например, если мы находимся на вызываемой стороне. То есть что-нибудь наподобие `return find_max(container, [] (T& x, T& y) { return less(y, x); }` — но без лямбд, т. к. они не «вписываются» в сигнатуру `find_max`. (Думаю, что это просто невозможно.)

Comment: @VladD  Если я вас правильно понял, то вы имеете в виду то, что я указал в новом дополнении к своему ответу.

Comment: Да, именно это! Я не ожидал, что `max_element( first, last, Greater<int>( cmp ) )` скомпилируется. Спасибо, выучил что-то новое для себя.

Answer (score 1):

Можно записать требующий обращения компаратор в переменную, локальную для потока. Поскольку пользовательский компаратор сам может вызвать `find_min` - старое значение этой переменной надо сохранить с стэке и восстановить перед выходом. А поскольку любое исключение может прервать обработку - придется воспользоваться приемом RAII.

Вот что получается:

```
thread_local bool(*inner_comp)(T&,T&);

bool reverse_comp(T&a, T&b) {
    return inner_comp(b, a);
}

class comp_scope {
    bool(*old_comp)(T&,T&);

public:
    comp_scope(bool(*new_comp)(T&,T&)) {
        old_comp = inner_comp;
        inner_comp = new_comp;
    }

    ~comp_scope() { 
        inner_comp = old_comp;
    }
}

...

template <typename T, size_t N>
T const& find_min(T (&a)[N], bool(*comp)(T&,T&)) {
    comp_scope _scope(comp);
    return find_max(a, reverse_comp);
}
```

PS Но, разумеется, все это - извращение. Надо менять тип параметра на `std::function` или даже на шаблонный. Тогда можно будет вместо него передать нормальное замыкание.

PPS если ключевое слово `thread_local` еще не поддерживается вашим компилятором - можно использовать `boost::thread_specific_ptr` (требуется boost)

Comment: Ну это немножко не reentrant (как бы сказать по-русски?). Что если сравнение внутри вызывает ту же функцию для своих частей? (Например, у нас список списков.)

Comment: Вот именно для обеспечения реентерабельности я и восстанавливаю старое значение переменной `inner_comp` при выходе из `find_min`. Некорректная работа будет лишь в одном случае - если `find_max` где-то сохраняет переданный компаратор, и он используется после выхода из `find_max`. Но функция поиска максимального элемента согласно своей документации должна быть чистой.

Comment: Ну, даже если функция поиска чистая, то её всё ещё может вызывать компаратор. И кроме того, думаю, речь не идёт о конкретно `std::max_element` (потому что тогда можно было бы воспользоваться `std::min_element` и не париться), функция, должно быть, приведена в качестве примера.

Comment: +1, особенно за первый PS.

Comment: @VladD, *вот именно для этого случая (компаратор вызывает функцию поиска) и я писал так сложно*!

Comment: А, точно, там scope! Тогда ещё один +1, виртуально.

Answer (score 0):

Агрументы поменяй местами и всё - теперь вместо меньше у тебя больше.